# How to 'require' a Racket module that doesn't have a #lang header line?

Tags: racket

As just one of many possible examples, [break-example.rkt](https://github.com/dfeltey/lwc2016/blob/master/examples/programs/break-example.rkt) would be a perfectly valid Java program, except for the `#lang mini-java` header that Racket requires.

So e.g. if I've written a Java interpreter/compiler in Racket as a Racket module language, how can I say, "`require` this file `Main.java` which is written in module language `mini-java` but doesn't have any Racket-specific header"?

(Note that I have almost non-zero practical experience with Racket. I'm evaluating this for a specific use case I have for Racket + DrRacket, which has nothing to do with Java by the way.  I searched the documentation but couldn't find any way to achieve this.)

Comment: The [_include/reader_](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/include.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Finclude..rkt%29._include%2Freader%29%29) form might be helpful to you; I can’t try it out right now but maybe you can experiment with it

Comment: @AlexKnauth Trying to get your answer to work, during that search I found https://groups.google.com/d/msg/racket-users/ECtWwJ7ti60/zB2UVQFCKAAJ which asks essentially the same question.

Comment: It appears that is using dynamic mechanisms to read, compile and evaluate the mini-java at runtime using `eval-syntax` and `dynamic-require`. That evaluates it gets it into a namespace but if the mini-java program provides identifiers, those identifiers won't be available in the rest of the file as they would be if you did `(require racket/list)` for example. The `include/reader` form would read and compile the mini-java at compile time, and make any identifiers it provides available to the requiring file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can’t run or test this right now, but maybe you can start from here and experiment with it. The main thing it uses is [`include/reader`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/include.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Finclude..rkt%29._include%2Freader%29%29):

```
#lang racket
(require racket/include
         syntax/parse/define
         (for-syntax racket/syntax
                     racket/port
                     syntax/modread))

(define-simple-macro (require/mini-java path)
  #:with modname (generate-temporary #'path)
  (begin
    (include/reader path (mini-java-reader 'modname))
    (require 'modname)))

(begin-for-syntax
  ;; Symbol -> [Any InputPort -> Syntax]
  (define ((mini-java-reader modname) src input)
    (cond
      [(port-closed? input) eof]
      [else
       (define stx
         (with-module-reading-parameterization
           (lambda ()
             (read-syntax src
               (input-port-append #t
                 (open-input-string "#lang mini-java\n")
                 input)))))
       (close-input-port input)
       (syntax-parse stx
         [(module _ l . b)
          #`(module #,modname l . b)])])))
```

Comment: Thanks for this!!  Seems to be on the right track, but can't get it to work yet, I get the error "include/reader: read error (read: #lang not enabled in the current context)".  Does this have to do with the [read-accept-reader](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-accept-reader%29%29) parameter?  I tried surrounding with `(parameterize ([read-accept-reader #t]) ...something...)` in a few places, but that doesn't seem to make it work...

Comment: The call to `with-module-reading-parameterization` should set the `read-accept-reader` parameter to true within its thunk's body, and the call to `read-syntax` within that body is where it should be needed... unless there's another context where the reader is called

Comment: I haven't tested it with `#lang mini-java` specifically, but I just tested it with `#lang sweet-exp racket`, and discovered an infinite-loop bug, which I just fixed in an edit. It now is working for that language... I'm not sure what the difference might be with `#lang mini-java`, can you tell me anything about that?

Comment: The mini-java was just an example.  I've tried to make your example code work with `#lang sweet-exp racket` but that still gives the same error.  My source code: https://gist.github.com/marnix/55361d56e67692ab32696abc80229f1d (rev 1).

Comment: I'm using DrRacket version 6.11 [3m] (on Linux), while I just see that the latest version is 7.2.  Could this be a 6 vs 7 issue?   \[I will try to get my hands on 7.2, and try the above code there.\]

Comment: Confirmed: With DrRacket 7.3 (on Windows) the above gist works fine.  \[Note that it requires the `sweet-exp-lib` package to be installed.\]  So I'll accept this answer.  And if anyone can make the code work on DrRacket 6 as well, that might help somebody at least for a little while...  Thanks again!